# Why Snakemake prefers calling script using script directive instead of calling from shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bioinformatics, snakemake

Snakemake rules in standardized workflows run Python scripts using the `script` directive, such as this template rule:

```
rule XXXXX:
    input:
        ...,
    output:
        ....,
    params:
        ...,
    conda:
        "../envs/python.yaml"
    script:
        "../scripts/XXXX.py"
```

Then in the script, it is possible to use `snakemake` object. However, the script is then tightly coupled with that rule, which seems a big disadvantage.

Why is this approach preferred to the approach using shell that calls the script, such as in this rule?

```
rule XXXXX:
    input:
        ...,
    output:
        ....,
    params:
        absolute_script_path = ..., # get
        argument1 = ..., 
    conda:
        "../envs/python.yaml"
    shell:
        "python {params.absolute_script_path} {input} {params.argument1} > {output}"
```

In this approach, python script is decoupled from the Snakemake rule. Also it looks more cohesive, as called arguments are clear from the rule, not hidden in the script.
I am only starting with writing Snakemake workflows, so I am just a beginner. I do not understand why the first approach is preferred (or used in standardized Snakemake workflows) to the second approach? Am I missing something? Are there some problems with the second approach?
Thank you very much for answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `script` approach is a bit more flexible in terms of the objects that the script can access via the `params` and other directives.

If you follow the `shell` approach you might find it cumbersome to (re) define the `argparse` or other approaches to properly take account of the arguments passed via `shell`. It's going to be mostly boilerplate, but can get somewhat tedious.

The `notebook` directive might be useful in scenarios that require interactive reproduction/development.

All in all, there are no hard rules, and for a given workflow one approach might be more suitable/convenient than other approaches.